# Unity Google Play Games Plugin: ERROR NOT AUTHORIZED CODE 13

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am trying to setup my google play games services plugin with unity. I am getting this error in logcat when I try to activate GPGS.

signin status: 13
ERROR NOT AUTHORIZED

Signin Status 13: is an unspecified error, no additional data is given

The google play sign in UI sometimes shows, (sometimes abruptly disapearing) but Google play games services never connects.

I am using google app signing. I have combed the internet for answers regarding google play games services and google app signing. None are working and I am not finding any others with a error code 13

Does anyone know what this error means or why I might be getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. I removed the ".EnableSavedGames()" from the PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder() statement. For some reason, savedgames was breaking the app and returning a signin status 13

Comment: There is a unity bug reporter within Unity3D if you think that this is a bug, might help someone out long run or you'll get the reason it didn't work! :)